# How to select a particular date from calendar?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

Hello Im using selenium ide, how to select an date from calendar popup through selenium ide,

Below is my calendar popup.

[image: Calendar]

Comment: Open the app in Firefox which has Firebug installed, right click on the particular date -> select "Inspect" and there will be the HTML code of the page containing the date selector's as well. It is perfect to create an XPATH expression which can be used to locate an element with webdriver/selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys, I just used my date id and selected the value and my date got selected.

```
command = click
target = id
value = 5,March,1989(for each date ,month and year should be seperately used)
```

(As each date has its own id in it there will be no problem in selecting a date using id and also the same case for month and year)